# How to exclude a post with a tag on wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, tags, content-management-system

I want to show 5 posts in the sidebar, EXCLUDING all those post I tagged "hp" (ID=11). Apparentely there are a lot of way to do that with categories, but with tags it is really hard to find.

Here is the code I have.

```
<?php query_posts( array( 'tag' => -11, 'posts_per_page' => 5, 'orderby' => 'date', 'order' => 'DESC' ) ); ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<?php if (class_exists('MultiPostThumbnails')
            && MultiPostThumbnails::has_post_thumbnail('post', '3-image')) :
                MultiPostThumbnails::the_post_thumbnail('post', '3-image'); endif; ?>
<div>in <?php   the_category(', '); ?></div>

<?php   the_title(); ?>
<?php
$count = 0;
$posttags = get_the_tags();
if ($posttags) {
foreach($posttags as $tag) {
$count++;
if ($count <= 1 ) {
echo '<a href="' . get_tag_link($tag->term_id) . '">' . $tag->name . '</a> ';
}
}
}
?>
  <?php endwhile;?>
```

It shows only 5 posts, showing only the first tag, but it keeps the posts with the tag I am trying to exclude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `WP_Query` class along with `tag__not_in`.

```
<?php
$the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'tag__not_in' => array( 11 ) ) );

while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();

     // Whatever you want to do goes here

endwhile;

// Reset Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

You can get more information about `WP_Query` class here - http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Comment: It works perfectly, thanks very much! But then how do I tell him to show only 5 posts?

Comment: You can supply same arguments as you were supplying earlier.